# how to find quantile of grouped variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following dataframe in r

```
No.        Key             Category
1          ABC123           0R1D
2          ABC567           0R1D
3          DEF444           1R1D
4          FRT433           1R1D
5          FRT433           1R1D
6          TYU412           2R2D
7          BEC123           0R1D
8          BCY567           0R1D
9          DEO444           1R1D
10         FRJ433           1R1D
11         FRK433           1R1D
12         TYL412           2R2D
```

I want to find unique key across all the categories and 4 quantiles of the same.
I am doing following in R

```
truck_quartile <- df %>% 
   group_by(Category) %>% 
   summarise(No_of_trailers = n_distinct(key)) %>% 
   do(data.frame(t(quantile(.$No_of_trailers, probs = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1))))) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
```

But it gives me only one row as I am summarizing it before quantiles.

Comment: What's the expected output

Comment: Expected output is category wise no of unique keys in all 4 quantiles

Comment: probably you need the `group_by` after `summarize`

Comment: 4 quantiles of what value ?

Comment: 4 quantiles of unique keys across categories.

Comment: Can u show the expected output?  If i do `quantile(c(4, 5, 2),  probs = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1))#
 25%  50%  75% 100% 
 3.0  4.0  4.5  5.0`

Comment: @akrun Key is basically the vehicle number. I want to find unique number of vehichles falls in different categories and their quantiles

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. "unique number of vehicles falls in different categories" is only one number for each `Category`. The result of that would be a vector of numbers. If you take quantile of that vector, you get a vector as a result as expected. Unless what you're really asking is the number of times each unique vehicle appears in each category. This makes more sense IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you will only get a single vector of quantiles with "unique number of vehicles falls in different categories" as expected. Below is for the case where you want to calculate **the quantiles of the number of times each unique vehicle appears in each category.**

```
library(dplyr)

truck_quartile <- df %>% 
  group_by(Category, Key) %>%
  summarize(No_of_trailers = n()) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  do(data.frame(t(quantile(.$No_of_trailers, probs = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1))))) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("Category", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"))
```

**Result with original df:**

```
  Category 25% 50% 75% 100%
1     0R1D   1   1   1    1
2     1R1D   1   1   1    2
3     2R2D   1   1   1    1
```

Your original `df` is a bit unfortunate since it only has one vehicle with duplicates in the same category. So I created `df_long` by sampling `df` with replacement.

**Result with `df_long`:**

```
  Category 25% 50% 75% 100%
1     0R1D   1   3   4    5
2     1R1D   3   4   6   11
3     2R2D   1   2   2    4
```

Note: Probably not a good idea to name variables with only numbers and special symbols, but it's fine if you only want a good looking table without actually using the columns for further calculation.

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)

df = fread("No.        Key             Category
           1          ABC123           0R1D
           2          ABC567           0R1D
           3          DEF444           1R1D
           4          FRT433           1R1D
           5          FRT433           1R1D
           6          TYU412           2R2D
           7          BEC123           0R1D
           8          BCY567           0R1D
           9          DEO444           1R1D
           10         FRJ433           1R1D
           11         FRK433           1R1D
           12         TYL412           2R2D")

set.seed(123)
df_long = data.frame(Key = sample(df$Key, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     Category = sample(df$Category, 100, replace = TRUE))
```